# After clicking outlook send button, appointment body is edited, need to send edited appointment body to all the participants

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook

I have an Outlook Addin. My requirement is that after outlook appointment send button, I must edit the URL in the appointment body and send the edited one to all participant.

Though the URL in appointment body is getting edited using my code (I could able to see in debug mode) but old content is being sent to participants.
Old content means appointment body before Send button click.

How to send the edited appointment body?

Answer (score 0):

Scenario:

If Developer want to change the Appointment body After clicking the Send button of Outlook Appointment Window.

The below three lines will help the developer to send the updated Appointment body to the participants:

```
private void Appointment_ItemSend(object item, ref bool cancel)
{
       // Write code to update the URL which is present in Appointment Body
       Outlook.MeetingItem ItemSendObject = item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
       ItemSendObject.Body = appointmentItem.Body;
       item = ItemSendObject;
}
```